Scenario Question on Spark Caching and Recomputation
Let's say I have 10 GB of source data and I perform a group by operation on it.
Then I'm caching it in memory only in spark. Obviously some partitions could not be saved due to memory contrainsts and has to be recomputed everytime.
My question is, how does it know which records to read from source? As data is shuffled due to group by, and some records from different partitions is already saved in memory, how does it know which records to read from source again to recompute?
I know that data lineage works at partiton level, so if it reads few partitions from source, obviously it'll have records which are already cached and even then it'll be recomputed, which is an overhead and also duplication of data happens.

To avoid this behaviour (just like you said data lineage works at partiton level) you can use checkpointing or persist to disk (MEMORY_AND_DISK).
